# Is webpack statically compiled?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Let's see example:

**my.js**

```
function fn2()
{
    console.log("I am fn2.");
}
export const fn1 = function (){
    console.log("I am fn1.");
}
```

**index.js**

```
import {fn1} from 'src/my'

function component() {
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  fn1();
  fn1 = 1;
  return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

I use `npx webpack --mode development`  to get **bundle.js**:

```js
--- something ---


/***/ "./src/my.js":
/*!*******************!*\
  !*** ./src/my.js ***!
  \*******************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

"use strict";
eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {\n/* harmony export */   \"fn1\": () => (/* binding */ fn1)\n/* harmony export */ });\nfunction fn2() {\n  console.log(\"I am fn2.\");\n}\n\nconst fn1 = function () {\n  console.log(\"I am fn1.\");\n};\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack://webpack-demo/./src/my.js?");


--- something ---
```

I find two problems:

- 1. It includes **unused** `fn2` function.
- 2. I assigned constant `fn1` with 1, but compile pass.

**Note:**
webpack 5.26.0

Comment: We need to see your npm scripts. If you don't enable tree-shaking then unused functions will still be included in the output.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "statically compiled"?

Comment: Why not use an eslint step before webpack to help with the code quality issues ? Why expect webpack to find these?